# Loading Flash / Flex Applications in another AIR Application

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

i'm loading a Flex Application in my AIR App and i'm using the `childSandboxBridge` and `parentSandboxBridge` to communicate between those two. Works like a charm.

But i've tried to load a Flash Application (the main Class extends `Sprite`, not `Application`) and therefore i get a SecurityError when trying to set the `childSandboxBridge` on the loaderInfo object.

In the Flex app it's like this:
I'm casting the loaderInfo since the `childSandboxBridge` Property is only available in AIR.

```
loaderInfo = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.loaderInfo;
try {
   Object(loaderInfo).childSandboxBridge = this;
} catch(e:Error) {
 ...
}
```

In my Flash app it's like this:

```
loaderInfo = myMainObject.loaderInfo; // myMainObject is the same class as 'root'
try {
   Object(loaderInfo).childSandboxBridge = this;
} catch(e:Error) {
 ...
}
```

In the below example i get the following SecurityError:

```
Error #3206: Caller app:/airapp.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/1 cannot set LoaderInfo property childSandboxBridge.
```

The SecuritySandbox for both examples is 'application'.

Any ideas why it doesn't work with the Flash app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly indicate in Flash code that you will allow it to be loaded into another VM. Check out the flash.system.Security class documentation for details:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html